# Can NumPy directly load data into a Fortran ordered array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I often work with data stored in text files with `[x, y, z]` like format.  When loading the data into a NumPy array, it is convenient to maintain the ordering from the text file, where each column is a different element, x, y, or z.  The downside to this is with the C ordering NumPy uses as the default, operating on all the x-values mean accessing non-contiguous memory blocks.

To load the data into a Fortran ordered array, I can use

```
data = numpy.asfortranarray(numpy.loadtxt('data.txt'))
```

but is there a way to do that in one line?  Looking at the [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) documentation, this method does not seem to provide that functionality.  Is there an another load function that does?

Comment: Do you realize that `loadtxt` can allocate memory for a row but not for a column beforehand? So the best it could do is read the array in C order and then convert it to F order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` read the file line by line and collect results in a list of lists (or list of tuples).  At the end they convert this to an array.  Roughly:

```
rows = []
for line in f.readline():
    values = [float(i) for i  in line.split(delimiter)]
    rows.append(values)
data = np.array(rows)
```

You could write your own reader!  Or just accept this extra bit of post processing.  It doesn't look hard or expensive.

Comment: That makes sense.  Essentially, because the file is stored in rows, to get a column-major array, Fortran ordering, the file has to be read in using row-major ordering, C ordering, then transformed.